# VBA: looping through Me.Multipage1.Pages(i)

Tags: vba

I need to acheive looping through hidden pages. I have 10 hidden pages with stacks of controls on each page.

What I need is to identify which page is next in line with something like:

```
Dim i as Integer 

For Each i In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i)

    If Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Visible = False Then

        'DO STUFF HERE

    End If

 Next i
```

I hope this explains. It is pretty simple, however I cannot find any looping documentation for checking Page(s).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should use a for loop?

Comment: in which program is that multipage object ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your style of coding version, and to loop from 0 until number of `Pages` you have in your `MultiPage1` control, you need to get the number of `Pages` with the command: `Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count`.

**Code**

```
Dim i       As Long

For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
    If Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Visible = False Then
        MsgBox "Page index " & i & " is hidden" ' <-- message box just for testing
        'DO STUFF HERE

    End If
Next i
```

---

### Edit 1

to support the new clarifications by the PO:

```
Dim i   As Long, j  As Long
Dim LastVisPg       As Long

For i = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Debug.Print MultiPage1.Pages(i).Caption
    If Not Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Visible Then
        For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Me.MultiPage1.Pages(j).Visible Then
                LastVisPg = j
                GoTo LastVisPageFound
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

LastVisPageFound:    
MsgBox "Last Visible Page index is  " & LastVisPg & ", Next unvisible page index is " & LastVisPg + 1

'=== OPTIONAL === : Set the next Page to Visible, and set the focus to it when the focus to this page
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(LastVisPg + 1).Visible = True ' unhide the next unvisible Page
Me.MultiPage1.Value = LastVisPg + 1 ' set focus to the next unvisible Page when User_Form loads
```

Comment: @user3803946  have you tried my answer and code above ? it will return you the index of the hidden page directly

Comment: I did and it works good. I just need to modify it to stop at the last

.Visible = True and +1 to enable the next page in line....

Comment: I have basically got a page with 10 hidden pages and there is a combobox than when an item is selected it unhides the next page in line

Comment: @user3803946 see edited code under **Edit 1**, in order to find the last visible `Page`, you need to first to make sure there is as Unvisible `Page` after, so you need to loop backwards on the `Pages`. let me know if it works now as you intended

Comment: yes this works a wonder. Now on to fix it repeating. If I hit the button to run the above script, it just keep adding a new one each time.. I need it to once run, not to keep adding new pages. BUt a good start

Comment: @user3803946 so if my answer and code here helped you solve the issue you raised in your post, then mark as "ANSWER", by clicking on the check mark next to my answer (it will turn green)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each pg In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
If pg.Visible = False Then

'Do something

End If
Next pg
```

**Edit About the second question:**

> "from the above: .Visible = True, what would I add to find the last .Visible = True and activate the page next to it. For example if it stops on Pages(4) Then add the next page (5)"

Add a variable to remember last visible page, like this:

```
Dim lastvisible As Integer
For Each pg In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
If pg.Visible = False Then
'set the varible to this page index
lastvisible = pg.index
'Do something

End If
Next pg
```

When the loop finishes the variable "lastvisible" will contain the index of the last visible page, you can now use it to set whatever you want about that page or any of the following
Example (setting the page next to the last visible page to visible):

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(lastvisible + 1).Visible = True
```

Comment: Nearly there. The next step was to check all of the pages. 

IF a page returns .Visible = true it need to check for the next spot and so on, until a .Visible = False return and then it will perform the ' Do Something action

Comment: I corrected the code above i thinks it fits your purpose now ;)

Comment: works well.. thanks..

can I add some complexity to it now:

from the above: .Visible = True, what would I add to find the last .Visible = True and activate the page next to it. For example if it stops on Pages(4) Then add the next page (5).

Comment: Added an explanation above